# Get local url for MvxStandardTableViewSource ImageUrl

Tags: binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind my viewmodel to the MvxStandardTableViewSource.

My binding text: `"DetailText MyDetail; TitleText MyTitle; ImageUrl MyImage"`

My ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string MyDetail { get; }
    public string MyTitle { get; }
    public string MyImage { get; }
}
```

I got the `DetailsText` and the `TitleText` working but I cannot figure out what the path should be for the `ImageUrl`

My image project path is: `My.Project.Name.Touch -> Resources -> myimage.png`

I have tried:

- `"myimage.png"`
- `Path.Combine("Resources", "myimage.png")`

Maybe I cannot use relative paths. In that case, how to get the complete path?

I have installed the following necessary nuget packages:

- `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache`
- `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File`

**How to get the proper image url string which makes it possible to bind to the ImageUrl?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For local images on iOS you must add **res:** prefix to your url string. Your image url might then look like this:

```
"res:myimage.png"
```

**Note:** The path above works if your images are placed in **Application root** or **Resources** folder. If you have your images in any other location then you must provide full path:

```
"res:YourPath/myimage.png"
```

That's because files in Resources folder are treated differently - they are copied to the root of the application.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct. You need to use the **res:** but you need to get rid of the `Resources`. Both `res:myimage` and `res:myimage.png` works. If you change your asnwer, I will accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the note. I did some investigation and you are right - images in Resources folder can't have `Resources` in front of them. I updated my answer.